# How to swap out child of a gameobject in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I want my player to pick up a gun prefab that is a dropped item then swap the old gun for a new gun. Current structure looks like this:
[image]

So the idea is my player picks up the prefab on the ground:
[image]

This what I tried. My idea was to instantiate a child to the player then somehow remove the Gun child and place the new gun in the same position. The fire point is already a child of my new prefab. So I just need to swap the two. The following script would be added to the drop on the ground.

```
public class WeaponPickUp : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject launcher;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void  OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
         if(col.gameObject.name =="Player"){

            GameObject go = Instantiate(launcher, new Vector3(0,0,0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            go.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }


}
```

Any ideas where to go from here? I'd really appreciate any kind of feedback.

Comment: Idk if I get you right... just delete your child by `Destroy(GameObject.Find("Player").transform.GetChild(0));` and then instantiate and set your new gun as child

Comment: [UnityScript](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript) != C#. This is C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to find the Player game object because the collision already detected it, and you can get the location of the gun you are replacing to use as the position for the new gun:

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        Vector3 spawnPosition = col.transform.GetChild(0).position;
        Destroy(col.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);
        Instantiate(launcher, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity, col.transform);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm actually not able to delete the the Gun object. I tried the code and it does not delete the gun object. The pick up and placement works perfectly. Any ideas?

Comment: The error I get is : Can't destroy Transform component of 'Gun'. If you want to destroy the game object, please call 'Destroy' on the game object instead. Destroying the transform component is not allowed.

Comment: I solved this part of the error by doing Destroy(col.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject); However the new issue is multiple gun pickups. When I pickup another gun, the first child gets deleted ( in this case it would groundcheck). So I would need to set the first child to the current picked up gun. Also, for some reason there are two instances of the picked up gun. Any ideas?

Comment: Edit: Solved by manually setting the gunprefab as the first child. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Attach script to your player. In Scene view adjust your gun position and the make the prefab that's it.

```
  public GameObject gunPrefab;
     void  OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
        if(col.gameObject.name =="gun"){
           Instantiate(gunPrefab, transform); //Instantiate(prefab, parent);
           Destroy(col.gameObject);
        }
}
```

Comment: This does not work, as it does not remove the gun child already existing. The pick up aspect works fine.

Comment: add this before Instantiate
`if(transform.Find ("gun"))Destroy (transform.Find ("gun").gameObject); // player already has gun in child`